# How can install tensorflow and keras in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I want to do time series recurrent neural network in R, but for this I trying to install tensorflow and keras for this

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()

library(keras)
install_keras()
```

calling library was ok but when everytime I enter `install_tensorflow()` or `install_keras()` below error appeared. I turned off my fire wall and I am not using VPN. I install python in my pc, my pc is `windows10 64bit`

```
C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Documents>CALL "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\condabin\activate.bat" "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate" 

C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Documents>conda.bat activate "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate" 

(r-reticulate) C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Documents>"C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed "tensorflow==2.8.*" 
Collecting tensorflow==2.8.*
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021A988BBDC0>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/17/5b/dac6e0607e4186b9e157597cd96d945aa769c60ef9f9f1b7ddc174f39332/tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021A988BBFA0>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/17/5b/dac6e0607e4186b9e157597cd96d945aa769c60ef9f9f1b7ddc174f39332/tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021A987511F0>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/17/5b/dac6e0607e4186b9e157597cd96d945aa769c60ef9f9f1b7ddc174f39332/tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021A98751310>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/17/5b/dac6e0607e4186b9e157597cd96d945aa769c60ef9f9f1b7ddc174f39332/tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021A98751490>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/17/5b/dac6e0607e4186b9e157597cd96d945aa769c60ef9f9f1b7ddc174f39332/tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/17/5b/dac6e0607e4186b9e157597cd96d945aa769c60ef9f9f1b7ddc174f39332/tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021A98751610>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))

Error: Error installing package(s): "\"tensorflow==2.8.*\""
In addition: Warning message:
In shell(fi, intern = intern) :
  'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCsn3wO\file38d45044492f.bat' execution failed with error code 1
```

can anyone help me with the installation?

Comment: The error message looks like the server that hosts the installation files is temporarily unavailable. Try again later.

Comment: Sir, I am trying for two days.

Comment: In that case this might be a firewall issue. Can you reach the domain `files.pythonhosted.org` from your machine at all?

Comment: It is showing a legal notice

Comment: It looks like you don't have full access to the internet. An unrelated comment: OneDrive has been observed to corrupt Python installations, you'll be better off keeping the Python installation out of one drive, and only keeping something like a lockfile in Onedrive.

Comment: Thank you sir, got the solutions, I detached onedrive from desktop and document settings, and now it works.